# Angularjs filter in controller. How to filter not null, undefined and false values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array:

```
        var array = [
            {"name": "name1", "value": null},
            {"name": "name2", "value": 3},
            {"name": "name3", "value": false},
            {"name": "name4", "value": undefined},
            {"name": "name5", "value": "some text"}
        ];
```

And now I want to filter this array in my angular controller to get items with values -

`{"name": "name2", "value": 3}` and

```
{"name": "name5", "value": "some text"}
```

So, I tryed this way (and it doesn't work):

```
data = $filter('filter')(data, { value: emptyOrNull(value) });
function emptyOrNull(value) {
    return !(value === null || value === undefined || value === false);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

a simple and effective way that can solve every problem it just tricky way but can help you out. it will handle everything `null, undefined, ('')`,false`

**just do this**

**`<span ng-repeat="entry in ctrl.array | filter:!!entry.value ">{{entry.name}} </span>`**

[working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ksEnuAd8TSahlbsYP7OV?p=preview)

**script.js**

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('FilterInControllerModule', []).
  controller('FilterController', ['filterFilter', function(filterFilter)  {

    this.array = [{
    "name": "name1",
    "value": null
}, {
    "name": "name2",
    "value": 3
}, {
    "name": "name3",
    "value": false
}, {
    "name": "name4",
    "value": undefined
}, {
    "name": "name5",
    "value": "some text"
}];

  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

**can also use custom filter ..**

```
.filter('customFilter',function(){
    return function(val,input){
      var result =[];
      angular.forEach(val,function(res){
        if(res.value && res.value.length || res.value){
           result.push(res);
        }

      });
      return result;

    }

  })
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example29-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="FilterInControllerModule">
  <div ng-controller="FilterController as ctrl">
  <div>
    All entries:
    <span ng-repeat="entry in ctrl.array | filter:!!entry.value ">{{entry.name}} </span>
  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

if you want to keep like your code you can simply do this.

```
data = $filter('filter')(data, {
    value: !!value
});
```

Comment: In your plunkr result window: All entries: name3.
It is not what I am expecting. Must be: All entries: name2 name5.

Comment: you mean value can be string , no problem keep one more param to check if it is string

Comment: matches your requirements .

Comment: Now it's matches my requirements, but I want filter array in controller (not in ng-repeat, but in javascript code).

Comment: why not in ng-repeat ? if you dont need in html then why to use filter just creation simple function

Comment: Because performance.  You should to avoid to use filters en view.